# Why I can't set easy transition, sidebar laggy

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problem with laggy in css transition, when click on fa-bars icon, sidebar showing with laggy.
I want to be easy smooth, but now when on click fa-bars icon my sidebar on start little laggy
I tried to solve using css transition `transition: all 0.2s ease;`

https://jsfiddle.net/y6m82puc/1/

HTML

```
<div class="mobile-navigation">

  <div class="header">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-nav-body">

    <ul>
      <li class="li">
        <a href="/"></a>
      </li>
      <li class="open-submenu li">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open-submenu li">
        <a href="#"></a> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open-submenu li">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="open-submenu li">
        <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="li">
        <a href="/onlinetv"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.mobile-navigation .mobile-nav-body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -230px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: #231111 !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    z-index: 999999999;

}
.mobile-menu-open .header{
    left:230px !important;
}

body {
    position: relative !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    left:0;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}    

body.mobile-menu-open {
    left: 230px;
}

body.mobile-menu-open .mobile-nav-body {
    left: 0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".fa-bars").on('click', function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('mobile-menu-open');
});
```

Comment: I cannot see any laggy behaviour. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: It's very smooth for me. Have you tried this on other devices and in other browsers?

Comment: problem is on mobile phone, I wan't to set easy smooth, like on this page
https://s.codepen.io/ncerminara/fullembedgrid/quJpi?type=embed&animations=stop-after-5#

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes of course

Comment: @ml92 The link you provided is 404. Also, you've now got 2 people telling you that the page in your fiddle isn't laggy, so it's more likely a device issue than a code issue.

Comment: Set time on 5s, and sidebar showing in chippings!